# How can I add mutiple included blocks in a concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hook, activesupport-concern

Everything is illustrated as follows:

```
# below is a common lib definition.
module SomeLib
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        puts 'executing predefined block from lib'
    end
end

# I want to expand the lib through my logic 
module SomeLib
    # errors: ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks 
    included do
        puts 'executing some actions defined by me'
    end
end
```

Then how to define extra included block when there has defined one in that module?